# Background image full width and height

Tags: html, css, background-image, scale

I'm setting up a banner for a website. The banner is consisting of an image, and some text on top of it, here's the code :

```
<div class="banner_div">
<style>
    .banner_div{
        background-image: url(/images/banner.jpg);
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-size: contain;
    }
</style>
<p class="banner_text">Line 1</br>Line 2</p>
</div>
```

What I need is for the image to cover the full width of the screen (even if the screen is wider than the image, in which case the image should strech) and the height of the div to scale accordingly so the image is fully displayed. How can I achieve this ? I tried every property of `background-size` but it didn't work...

Edit : the current problem is that the height scales tho the one of the text

Comment: `background-size: cover`?

Comment: background-size: cover; or background-size: 100% 100%;

Comment: background-size: cover;

Comment: Based on your edit: if you want 100% of screen height, use viewport units, e.g. height: 100vh, otherwise height = height of content, if specific fixed height is not set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following solution:

```css
body, html {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.banner_div {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/100x100);
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner_div">
  <p class="banner_text">Line 1</br>Line 2</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I have a better solution for your issue.

The problem is because you are not giving height for HTML,BODY.
if you gave the height this issue will be solved, no need to add position  elements to this, it will make some alignment issue in future

**SOLUTION**

HTML

```
<div class="banner_div">
<p class="banner_text">Line 1</br>Line 2</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
    html,body{
      height:100%;
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
    }
    .banner_div{
        background-image: url(http://placehold.it/100x100);
        background-size: cover;
         background-position: center;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }
    .banner_text{
      margin:0;
      padding:20px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="banner_div">
<p class="banner_text">Line 1</br>Line 2</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly use a 16:9 image for better results:

Then use `img` tag itself,

Scaling the image without its aspect ratio into consideration may not look good for a banner, So we use `width:100%` and `height:auto` to preserve banner ratio.
Most screen uses 16:9 ratio, so it should be good if you have a 16:9 image

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

.banner{
  display:block;
  }

.banner img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.banner p {
  float:left;
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">

  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7c/Aspect_ratio_16_9_example.jpg" />
  <p>Some text here</p>
</div>

Some random text to show other elements wont overlap the banner
```

Answer (score 0):

This `css` code working with me :

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```