# How can i set height and width of background image of button?

Tags: html, css

i just want to set properly height and width of background image of button that picture mentioned here!

```
float:right;
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
border-radius: 50%;
```

[image]

Comment: Please show us the CSS code that adds the background, and also the HTML for the button would be helpful so we can show it to you working :)

Comment: There are already [lots of similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=css+background+image+size) with answers to this on the site: [Background image full width and height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40673586/background-image-full-width-and-height) or [Fit background image to div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200204/fit-background-image-to-div). Please check the site first before posting to see if an answer (or lots of them! ) already exist before posting... see [ask]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `background-image` with `background-size: 100%`.

```css
button{
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdaRR.png");
  float :right;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-size: 100%;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<button></button>
```

Comment: Your contributions are welcome, but please note that answering duplicate questions like this is against Stack Overflow guidelines. Otherwise we are just encouraging more poor questions :) Please see the "Answer well-asked questions" section in [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Instead the correct action is to flag the question and link to with one of the already existing answers. Or simply just move on to well-asked questions :)

Answer (score 2):

You are missing background-size property:

```
background-size: contain;
```

```css
button {
  float:right;
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdaRR.png');
  background-size: contain;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<button></button>
```

Comment: yes this works thank you

Comment: Please add code answers as a Stack Snippet using the `[<>]` button in the answer editor - there is no need to go to an external site. Or better yet, flag questions that have been asked before and have lots of existing answers as **duplicate** instead of answering, as per the SO guidelines, instead of adding more "clutter" to the site :) See [answer]